# показано 100 лучших из 377 доступных знаков

Tags: дефект, дизайн, знаки

> показано 100 лучших из 377 доступных знаков, пожалуйста, используйте окно поиска, чтобы найти определённый знак.

1. Это сообщение **оформлено просто ужасно**.
2. **Оно неверное**: 100 из 377, но 100 не делится на 3, а значит показано не 100, поскольку все ряды полные. Полагаю, что там 102, а не 100.
3. **Оно не учитывает фильтр**: золотых знаков всего 5, а не 100 и, тем более, не 377.
4. **Мне интересно видеть все** - раньше показывались все метки, с которыми я хоть как-то взаимодействовал, даже если по ним был отрицательный рейтинг, и мне было интересно на них посмотреть. А теперь только поле поиска. Брррррррр...

> [image: скриншот всех]
>
> [image: скриншот золотых]

Comment: 100 знаков - это для закладки "Доступно", судя по всему.

Comment: @PashaPash, хм.. все полученные плюс 100 доступных? Ну возможно. Но показывается-то на всех вкладках. И вообще, неудобно.